# ¿ Cómo puedo subir de un proyecto Laravel y Angular por FTP (no CPanel)?

Tags: ftp

He realizado un pagina web usando Laravel y Angular, pero ahora me dispongo a subirla a el servidor de IONOS.
Pero nunca lo he hecho antes y no he encontrado nada información.

La tengo alojada en un Wampserver para desarrollo.

Despues de subir los datos

1º -- BD
    La exporte de local y la subí a producción. Después modifique el fichero .env (Laravel), para que los datos del servidor fueran los correctos.

2º -- Angular:
Con el comando ng build, prepare el proyecto, lo subi y seleccione que el domino cogiera la carpeta. Se muestra todo, pero claro no funciona el backend.

3º -- Laravel
Despues subi la parte de Laravel (sin la carpeta “public”).

Después de esto, no se me ocurre nada mas.

¿ Como puedo hacer que se relacionen correctamente ?
¿ Puede no ser la carpeta de Angular la principal, pero mostrando en frontend ?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes ocupar como cliente FTP FileZilla. Ahi le configuras los parametros necesarios que te brinda IONOS para que puedas conectarte de manera segura.

1. Abra FileZilla
2. Introduzca la dirección del servidor en el campo Servidor, ubicado en la barra de Conexión rápida

   - (sftp.example.com - asegúrese de introducir sftp para conectarse de forma segura a través de SFTP)
3. Introduzca su nombre de usuario

   - (example.com - mantenerlo en minúsculas y sin "www.")
4. Introduzca su contraseña

   - (La que elegió para SSH en su panel de control)
5. Introduzca el puerto.

   - (Puerto 22 para SFTP)
6. Haga clic en Conexión rápida o presione Enter para conectarse al servidor.
7. Haga clic en Aceptar cuando reciba una advertencia acerca de una clave de host desconocido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te he colocado los pasos a seguir, cuando te conectes ya empiezas a crear tus carpetas y subir tus archivos.

Comment: Me sirvio para subir los datos, Gracias.

Comment: Pero continuación en la desarrolló, con el terminal prepare la parte de Angular con el comando ng build. I lo subi.
Despues subi la parte de Laravel (sin la carpeta “public”).

Comment: No funciona, si eligo como la carpeta contenedora del dominó, el directorio dist (Angular) se muestra pero no puede interactuar con Laravel.

Comment: Angular solo corre bajo el servidor de node.js, consulta en tu servidor IONOS si puedes implementar dentro node.js para hacer funcionar tu proyecto de Angular